# Mono ASP.NET COM Reference

Tags: com, mono

Is there any way to reference a tlb export on Mono?

I am really stuck with .NET on one of my only remaining projects on MS platforms and would like to move away from it.  The only problem is that the web site is dependent on a COM library that is simply a socket wrapper enforcing a messaging protocol.  I could reverse the code (I actually made a 10k line attempt) but there's nothing better than the original if it works.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
The link is much appreciated, but I noticed a reference to xptimport but nothing more.  Anyone know of a way to currently implement a COM reference in Mono for a non-Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**COM Interop in Mono**
http://www.mono-project.com/COM_Interop